# How to install KDE without Konqueror?

Tags: debian, kde, dependencies, konqueror

I want to install a very minimal KDE desktop in Debian. When running `apt-get install kde-plasma-netbook`, `kde-plasma-netbook` depends on `kde-baseapps`, which then installs some applications, such as konqueror, which I do not need. Is there any way to install KDE without installing this Web browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install just `kde-runtime` and `kde-workspace` packages.